# Change the state of the item in recyclerview with pagination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination, state

I've implemented the recycler view with pagination. In my list item, there is information and the favorite icon for a set like and unlike the item. When setting the like, Icon will be enabled otherwise disabled. It's working correctly but when I scroll it's again showing the disabled icon. I've researched and found the below override methods which I generally used for the normal recycler view.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position;
}
```

But my recycler view is with the pagination and I've used the below methods.

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (position == assistanceArrayList.size - 1 && isLoadingAdded) LOADING else ITEM
}
```

Help me out to prevent the changing state on scrolling the recycler view.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to the changing state of the list item while scrolling the scroll view. I've set the Nestedscrollview of the parent of recycler view and added the below line while setting the adapter.

```
adapter!!.setHasStableIds(true)
```

In my fragment, I've added the below line

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mFragmentAssistanceBinding!!.recyclerViewAssistanceLog, false)
```

The issue has been resolved. I hope it'll help others. :)